# Colab missing file

Tags: file, google-colaboratory

I was working with my Colabfile for about 4 month but it disappeared from my Google drive. It was deleted completely, not even in Trash. I also received a message that the link of this file is not correct. Any one can help please?

I also contacted Google but they replied that they don't provide technical support.